# Problem with text deletion in vi editor

Tags: command-line, vi

When I am writing C code on the vi editor, I am not able to use the backspace keys or my arrow keys to delete or navigate through lines. Some unexpected special characters occur on the screen that is on middle of my code and I am not able to delete them also. If I use my delete key, the whole code gets deleted. I have tried both insert mode using '<kbd>i</kbd>' and '<kbd>a</kbd>'. I am able to manage this situation for C programming by using the text editors but when I am creating LeX and yacc programs, I find this awkward.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: If you have made a mistake, press the Escape to get into navigation mode, and use the Delete key. After that you can press i to get in insert mode again.

Comment: Also, if you can, install vim (if not installed already): `sudo apt-get install vim`. Vi will become a bit easier to use (you won't have problems with the delete and arrow keys) and it will add other things like syntax-highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

Help with the *vi* editer and its commands-

[Vi Editor Commands](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~cslab/vi.html)

[How to use the vi editor](https://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/vi.html)

Answer (score 1):

When in command mode (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) you can delete character/word/lines and paragraphes using several keystrokes. Below a some examples.:

**Characters**:

- <kbd>x</kbd> Delete char under cursor
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> Delete char before cursor

**Word**

- <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> Delete line under cursor
- <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> Delete inner word under cursor. E.g pressing this stroke when on `"delete"` will endup in `""`.
- <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> Delete whole word under cursor, including parenthesis etc. E.g. pressing this stroke on `"delete"` will delete every character.

**Paragraphs**

- <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> Delete inner paragraph under cursor.
- <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> Delete whole paragraph under cursor, including parenthesis etc.

Putting a number in front of the modifier key strokes will repeat the action those amount of times. E.g. <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> will delete 3 characters.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it easily by typing the following command:

```
vi ~/.vimrc
```

After creating the file you add the below lines in to it:

```
set backspace=2
```